# Is there a good way to visualize progress for the end user?

Tags: python, add-on

I'm currently working on an addon that renders animations at many different angles. Think isometric sprites. Currently Blender just hangs while it's doing its work. Is there a loading bar, or some kind of adhoc popup I can access via code to give the end-user a visual update of what's going on?

The one thing I'm going to be picky about is a solution on the console - most users will not have that open. Unless, of course, there's a way I can force the console to appear.

Comment: Have you used command line rendering? I'm actually writing a GUI application to make it easy for artists to enter their parameters and automatically launch a command line render. When you launch a command line render, you can see it logging the rendering progress. So, I'm not sure what you mean by the the console to appear. As far as visualizing progress, I've actually searched and searched for this functionality with C++ and haven't found anything.

Comment: I found this along the way of my search and might help you since you want to work in python. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28925/how-to-get-actual-rendering-progress-and-estimation-from-render-stats-python-han
you can follow the rabbit hole.

Comment: While you might be able to use [threads](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_gotcha.html#strange-errors-using-threading-module) to stay responsive during render I don't think you can get the progress from `bpy.ops.render.render()`, I expect using the [subprocess module](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/45731/935) to be the answer, you can use `bpy.app.binary_path` to start another blender in the background and parse it's output for progress.