# Is it possible to get total render time via Python code?

Tags: rendering

Is it possible to get total render time via Python code when render’s done?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Render Handlers**

Borrowing heavilly from 
[Is it possible to get render time per tile?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2642/is-it-possible-to-get-render-time-per-tile)

Test code prints the total time elapsed from render init handler being fired, to render complete (or cancel)

```
from datetime import datetime
from bpy.app import handlers

FRAME_START_TIME = None
RENDER_START_TIME = None

def handler_function(name):
    def handler(scene):
        print(name)
    return handler

frame_handlers = [getattr(handlers, name)
        for name in dir(handlers) if name.startswith("render_")]

def add_dummy_handlers():
    for  handler in frame_handlers:
        handler.append(handler_function(name))   

def clear_handlers():
    for  handler in frame_handlers:
        handler.clear()

def render_init(scene):
    global RENDER_START_TIME
    RENDER_START_TIME = datetime.now()  
    print("Render Start")  

def render_pre(scene):
    global FRAME_START_TIME
    FRAME_START_TIME = datetime.now()

def render_stats(dummy):
    print("Elapsed:", datetime.now() - FRAME_START_TIME)

def complete(scene):
    print("Total:",  datetime.now() - RENDER_START_TIME)

def cancel(scene):
    print("CANCELLED.... After:",  datetime.now() - FRAME_START_TIME)

clear_handlers()

handlers.render_init.append(render_init)
#handlers.render_pre.append(render_pre)
#handlers.render_stats.append(render_stats) # write or post ?
handlers.render_complete.append(complete)
handlers.render_cancel.append(cancel)
```

Output of a 4 frame render animation.

```
Render Start
Saved: '/tmp/0000.png'
 Time: 00:01.06 (Saving: 00:00.48)

Saved: '/tmp/0001.png'
 Time: 00:00.92 (Saving: 00:00.26)

Saved: '/tmp/0002.png'
 Time: 00:00.87 (Saving: 00:00.25)

Saved: '/tmp/0003.png'
 Time: 00:00.97 (Saving: 00:00.32)

Total: 0:00:03.846082
```

Added code from https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/62870/15543 to clear the handers `clear_handers()`, and also to add a set of dummy handlers that simply print their name when called. `add_dummy_handlers()`

Comment: Wow! That's complicated... I'll try this out, thanks.