# How to show expected remaining render time

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

When rendering animation, the info in the top-left corner of the render window shows the time per rendered frame. Is there a way to also have the **expected remaining render time for the whole animation** showing?

Comment: Similarly to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133114/is-it-possible-to-get-total-render-time-via-python-code  could estimate based on average time.

Comment: There is an add-on for this problem called [Render Estimation](https://blendermarket.com/products/render-time-estimation-add-on)

Answer (score 2):

Blender does not have the function to show complete animation render time. Best option is average render time multiplied by remaining frames. It should be noted that render time changes according to what is visible on screen. Its actually quite hard to know ahead of time how much time is needed per frame and it can also be affected by other processes other than Blender running on the computer.

Comment: Lame it  doesn't have this natively. In Lightwave, it just shows you estimates based on render time up to then, you still have to mentally predict the LOD for upcoming frames, but waaaay better than trying to do math from flashing numbers. if only they just stayed on screen.

Comment: Pretty lame indeed. It's not that hard... wonder why they didn't do it. Found [a plugin](https://blendermarket.com/products/render-time-estimation-add-on) but it's $6