# What values should I be passing for self and context in my python script

Tags: python

I'm trying to call a method from within the same class. I've found that if I have no args apart from self and context, I can simply call it using 'UpdateObjectProperties' and it works perfectly. However I want to add other arguments to it and when I do that I have to add in self and context too. I don't know what values to add there to get it to work. I've included an exert of my script here. Not the whole thing as it is several hundred lines long but that should include all necessary info. There will be more enum properties calling the method than just AIInput. Any ideas?

````
#Input field information can be found here
class PanelProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    """Input field information"""                  
                
    #Create a tuple containing the objects shape keys            
    def GetVisemeList(self, context):
        curIndex = 0
        ListForTuple = []
        for shapekey in bpy.context.active_object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks.keys():
            currentKeyIdentifier = shapekey
            currentKeyName = shapekey
            currentKeyInfo = ""
            newTuple = (currentKeyIdentifier, currentKeyName, currentKeyInfo)
            ListForTuple.append(newTuple)
            curIndex = curIndex + 1                    
        FinalTuple = tuple(ListForTuple)
        return FinalTuple  
    
    #This method is called when the property is updated. It is the one I'm having trouble with.
    def UpdateObjectProperties(self, context, stringName, value):
        scene = bpy.context.scene
        if 'TextToSpeech_toolprops2' in scene:           
            obj = bpy.context.active_object
            rna_ui = obj.get('_RNA_UI')
            if rna_ui is None:
                obj['_RNA_UI'] = {}
                rna_ui = obj['_RNA_UI']
        
            obj[stringName] = value
        
            rna_ui[stringName] = {"description":stringName,
                    "default": "",
                    "min":0,
                    "max":1,
                    "soft_min":0,
                    "soft_max":1}
                    
    #Info for the inputs is found here
            
    AIInput : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name= "AI",
        description = "Viseme Shape",        
        items = GetVisemeList,
        update = UpdateObjectProperties('self = ??????', 'context = ??????', "AI", bpy.types.scene.TextToSpeech_tool.AIInput)
        
class TEXTTOSPEECHANIM_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a panel in the main window for the Text to Speech Animation Tool"""
    bl_label = "Text To Speech Animation"
    bl_idname = "TEXTTOSPEECHANIM_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Text To Anim"
    
    
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.TextToSpeech_tool
        mytool2 = scene.TextToSpeech_toolprops2        
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text = ".wav directory")
        layout.operator(OT_IdentifierFileSelector.bl_idname, icon="FILE_FOLDER", text="Select .wav file")
        layout.label(text = bpy.context.scene.TextToSpeech_toolprops2.AudioDirectory)
        layout.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname, text="Get Sentence Data")
        layout.prop(mytool2, "StartFrame")
        layout.prop(mytool2, "FramesPerSecond")
        layout.operator(SimpleOperator2.bl_idname, text="Animate")   

classes = [PanelProperties, TEXTTOSPEECHANIM_PT_main_panel]


def register():
    SimpleOperator
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
        
    bpy.types.Scene.TextToSpeech_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type= PanelProperties) 
    
def unregister():
    SimpleOperator
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        del bpy.types.Scene.TextToSpeech_tool        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()   
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is an update callback.**

Started as a long comment, will throw it together as an answer Will hunt down some links that explain this (probable dupes).

This is what I think you are after

[Using a single worker method for properties](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39609/using-a-single-worker-method-for-properties)

[Centralizing properties updates in one function?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/205120/centralizing-properties-updates-in-one-function)

Firstly going to suggest that if `context` is passed as an argument use it, not `bpy.context`  *Possibly only semantics atm, but if it changes such that the context passed doesn't match global context will cause all sorts of issues...*

In the API docs style guide it is recommended to use CamelCase for class names, hence for clarity have changed method & property names to snake_case to coincide with the rest of blender.

The value assigned to `update, get, set` and `items` (if `items` is to be dynamically built via callback) are methods.  Consult the `bpy.props` docs. `update` and `items` are expected to  have arguments `(self, context)`  a getter `(self)` and a setter `(self, value)` where `value` is the `value` being set.

```
def get_viseme_list(self, context):
    ...
    # return the enum items as a list

def update_viseme_list(self, context):
    # self is in this case scene.tts_tool
    # self.id_data is scene
    # the value being updated is self.ai_input

    print(self, self.id_data, self.ai_input)

ai_input : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
    name= "AI",
    description = "Viseme Shape",        
    items = get_viseme_list,
    update = update_viseme_list
)
```

at issue here somewhat is you have defined a scene property that both populates from & updates the context object, that's Ok I suppose if that is the intention, albeit somewhat confusing.  Especially in the case of

```
scene = bpy.data.scenes["Some other not context scene"]
scene.tts_tool.ai_input = 'P'
```

in which case `context.object` may or may not be an object of the scene.

Consider instead using

```
bpy.types.Object.tts_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type= PanelProperties)
```

(or `Mesh` or even `Key`)

Go Cats.

Comment: I think that first link you posted is spot on in terms of what I'm after. I apologize for any confusing naming conventions and code. I am very new at this. Thank you for taking the time to answer :). I'll use your suggestions.

Comment: Cheers, happy to help, & abs no apologies necessary.  Will close as dupe of first link.

Answer (score 0):

But why do you want constant values as parameters? You could just use the normal use case you know with the two parameters and "read"/use your values inside the function.

Comment: Because the AIInput EnumProperty values aren't the only ones I'm going to be using. There are about ten and to keep things neat I don't want to have to repeat the method that many times.