# Is 3D viewport render time exposed in python?

Tags: python

When 3D viewport is in render mode, ie [`SpaceView3D.viewport_shade = 'RENDERED'`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.viewport_shade) Can the  render time be gleaned or estimated using python?

[image]
*3D view in rendered mode taking 12.63 seconds.*

Answer (score 1):

[As far as I](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?329291-Print-or-output-current-Frame-Tile-Sample-(Render-)Time-Information) know this is implemented in C and [no accessible with the python API](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2642/is-it-possible-to-get-render-time-per-tile).

However you can probably create a handler for scene_update which:

- iterates over all areas and check if area type is 3d view
- if so check if the view type is rendered
- and if it is start a timer and use some approximation algorithm to record the time
- however if the view type is not rendered or there are no 3d views and the timer is running, stop the timer.

Read more:
[Render Time Estimation Addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Render_Time_Estimation)

[Cycles Time Estimation](https://github.com/JrMasterModelBuilder/Cycles-Render-Time-Calculator)